# How to open LWC on full screen on a Quick action?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

[image]I have LWC and i called that on a custom quick action. But it is not opening on full screen.
can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: what you mean is not full screen? can you add your code and images in your question

Comment: Do you mean to say, it's not opening at all when in Full Screen mode (F11), or it is not taking up the full screen? Some screenshots and code would definitely be useful here.

Comment: Added, i means when i click on my quick action button it will not open on full screen, it open like a modal

Comment: That's helpful. What are you expecting it to look like, exactly?

Comment: I want it should be display on full screen. I tried to put css but it will not open in full screen means on full page

Comment: Quick action by default will open only as a modal. You will have to create a lightning app page and add your component to the page and when the quick action is clicked you can open that lightning page and close your lwc modal after it programmatically.